# Horizontal Timeline with CSS (or Bootstrap)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I create horizontal timeline? Going through example, I created my own vertical timeline but I couldn't transform it to horizontal timeline.

```
<style>
.container {
    background:none;
    width:80%;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow:auto;
    padding:2%;
}
.right-content, .left-content {
    float:left;
    display:block;
    width:40%;
    padding:1% 2%;
}
.left-content {
    border-right:10px dotted #666;   
    text-align:right;
}
.left-content p {
    margin:150px 0 0;
}
.right-content p {
    margin:80px 0 150px;
}
.container p {
-webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.7 ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;   
}
.left-content .more-padding {
  padding-right:100px;
}
.right-content .more-padding {
  padding-left:100px;
}
</style>
    <div class="container">
               <div class="left-content">
                  <p>Content 01</p>
                  <p>Content 02</p>
                  <p>Content 03</p>
                  <p>Content 04</p>
                  <p>Content 05</p>
               </div>
               <div class="right-content">
                  <p>Content 01</p>
                  <p>Content 02</p>
                  <p>Content 03</p>
                  <p>Content 04</p>
                  <p>Content 05</p>
               </div>
            </div>
```

This is an example drawing of what I'm looking for. [image].

Comment: Since every `<p>` is a new line, you cant build an horizontal timeline with this label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would refactor your HTML so that your timeline content shows in order. Currently, on your vertical timeline, the chronological order (01, 01, 02, 02, ... 05, 05) does not match your DOM presentation (01, 02, ... 05, 01, 02, ... 05). For a horizontal timeline you should use `absolute` positioning along your timeline wrapper and position each timeline item `top` or `bottom` of the timeline `div`. Also, you should use `<ul>` and `<li>` for better syntax.

If you are interested in a more complex design, go ahead and glean from an existing solution:

https://codyhouse.co/demo/horizontal-timeline/ is a nice custom option.

https://timeline.knightlab.com/ gives you plenty of options, is quite flexible and allows you to manage your timeline content in a Google Sheet.